# Why permissions does not work with my .apk in play store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

When developping my Android app (with cordova), I have a strange behaviour:

When transfering the app from my computer to the tablet in debug mode, everything works well.
But when I upload it on Google Play Store, then downloading it to my tablet, it seems permissions are missing.
Indeed, I set 5 permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

But after that, when installing the app from the play store, a pop up says the app need only 2 permissions:

- Camera
- Device ID

Then, I accept, I install it, but when I launch the app, it can not access internet.

Here is the entire Manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="20100" android:versionName="2.1.0" package="com.ionicframework.magnetiztablet479260" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your entire manifest. If you are using Android Studio, you might wish to examine your final manifest, after all mergers have been done, in `build/intermediates/manifests/` of your application module. You might also consider linking to the app's listing in the Play Store.

Comment: Google does not show Internet access permission during install from Play Store for some time now (it's treated as obvious). You can click on the permissions on the bottom of the play store page, it should show up there.

Comment: @poss Thanks for this information. I don't see exactly when I can find detailed permissions on the play store page.

Comment: @CommonsWare I posted entire Manifest. I'm using Ionic/Cordova to create my application. In ant-build/ folder, I found an AndroidManifest.cordova.xml, but it's exactly the same that the normal Manifest.

Comment: You can try moving your `<uses-sdk>`, `<uses-permission>`, and `<uses-feature>` elements to appear before the `<application>` element. "I don't see exactly when I can find detailed permissions on the play store page" -- you will find a "Permissions" header with a "View details" link towards the bottom of each app's listing on the Play Store.

Comment: http://imgur.com/2xkAnNn This is from some random app on store. Network access doesn't show up unless you click on "Permission details"

Comment: try put it between uses-sdk and application

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right, I can eventually see that all permissions are there:https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2zjngj0hh8a21g/Screenshot%202015-08-26%2021.03.51.png?dl=0 I'll try moving permissions in the manifest, but it would be strange that that solves the problem right?

Comment: "I can eventually see that all permissions are there" -- then your problem with accessing the Internet has to do with the Internet, not the permissions.

Comment: Internet is actually OK here. But when sending the app to the tablet with cordova run --device`, it works, but when uploading to the store, it seems that there is no internet access (but internet does work). So weird!